# EOFException trying to reading DataInputStream

Tags: java

I am getting an EOFException and I'm not sure why? I tried many things to figure it and changed my code up and directory, but it's not fixing.

Edit: Added my writer code because this is confusing on why it is doing this, it is unusual

I did other things like, catch the EOFException that didnt work, and I even tried to reading to it through the debugger, and the debugger shows that it read my first variable for accNum and then crashed right after.

```
try {

            DataInputStream read = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("accounts.bin"));

            while (read.available() > 0) {

                int accNum = read.readInt();
                String accName = read.readUTF();
                String accType = read.readUTF();
                double balance = read.readDouble();

                System.out.println(accNum + " " + accName + " " + accType + " " + balance);
            }
        } catch (IOException e ) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
 try {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("accounts.txt"));
            int index = 0;
            int accNum = 0;
            String accName = "";
            double balance = 0;
            String accType = "";

            ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    accNum = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    index++;
                } else if (index == 1) {
                    accName = input.nextLine();
                    index++;
                } else if (index == 2) {
                    accType = input.nextLine();
                    index++;
                } else if (index == 3) {
                    balance = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());

                    accounts.add(new Account(accNum, accName, balance, accType));
                    index = 0;
                }
            }

            input.close();

            FileOutputStream accountTxtFile = new FileOutputStream("accounts.bin");

            DataOutputStream accountBinFile = new DataOutputStream(accountTxtFile);


            for (Account accountObj : accounts) {

                accountBinFile.writeUTF(Integer.toString(accountObj.getAccountNumber()));
                accountBinFile.writeUTF(accountObj.getAccountHolderName());
                accountBinFile.writeUTF(accountObj.getAccountType());
                accountBinFile.writeUTF(Double.toString(accountObj.getBalance()));

                // Checking my work lol
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(accountObj.getAccountNumber()));
                System.out.println(accountObj.getAccountHolderName());
                System.out.println(accountObj.getAccountType());
                System.out.println(Double.toString(accountObj.getBalance()));
            }



            accountBinFile.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since accName, accNum, accType, and balance are decoded from the same data, I believe they cannot all be parsed at the same time without more specification.

Comment: Can you show us how the file was written?

Comment: You're writing e.g. the integer as a string of UTF-8 digits, and reading it as a 4-byte binary value. so everything goes to hell after that.  See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt()) for readInt.

Comment: @undefinedsymbol so how would I fix this, im fairly new to java and im still trying to learn

Comment: Decide whether you want your file to be binary (as its name suggests) or text (as your code actually writes).  Use matching read and write calls - writeInt for readInt, for example.  Above all, [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) for every class you use.  I/O is a bit of a maze, it's true, but you can find your way around after a while.

Comment: If you particularly *need* to do this with binary data, you'd be much better off using `ObjectInputStream` and read an `Account` object